# How do I retrieve user information once the user is created and navigate to a different screen

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a small android studio kotlin project that have a few screen like the user creation, the login and the home activity page for now that use the FirebaseAuthentication class function.
I can create user and login and it will navigate me to the home page but when I try to update the data in the cloud firestore, the document name is different. would someone help me to retrieve the current user once I navigate to a different activity. In the home page I try to get the current user but it's not working. I appreciated any help

```
class FirebaseAuthentication {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var firestoreDatabase: FirebaseFirestore


    //create user and their email and their name
    fun createUser(email: String, password: String, name: String) {

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        firestoreDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {

                val user = auth.currentUser
                if (user != null) {
                    //user is sign in
                    val userName = hashMapOf(
                            "Name" to name,
                            "User ID" to user.uid
                    )

                    //set the document name as the user input name instead of
                    //using User UI for simplicity
                    firestoreDatabase.collection("Users").document(name).set(userName)

                } else {
                    //no user is sign in
                }


            } else {

            }
        }

    }

    //logging user in
    fun logTheUserIn(email: String, password: String) {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    }


    //save data in the cloud firestore database
    //it will further add more user info
    fun saveData() {

    }

    //update the user data
    fun updateDocumentField() {

    }

}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var myButton : Button
    private lateinit var myEmail : EditText
    private lateinit var myPassword : EditText
    private lateinit var logginBtn : Button
    private lateinit var userName : EditText
    private lateinit var createUser : FirebaseAuthentication



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setTitle("Firebase create user Page")
        
        myButton = findViewById(R.id.createUser)
        myEmail = findViewById(R.id.email)
        myPassword = findViewById(R.id.password)
        logginBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin)
        userName = findViewById(R.id.name)
        createUser = FirebaseAuthentication()

        //this will create user
        myButton.setOnClickListener{

            createUser.createUser(myEmail.text.toString(),myPassword.text.toString(),userName.text.toString())

            //if user creation is successful
            //then take them to the home page
            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, HomePage::class.java))
        }

        //this will login the user in
        logginBtn.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, Login::class.java))
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

```
class HomePage : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mAuth : FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var display : TextView
    private lateinit var signoutButton : Button
    private lateinit var database : FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var uploadData : Button
    private lateinit var textToBeUpload : EditText


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page)
        setTitle("this is the home page")

        display = findViewById(R.id.textView2)
        signoutButton = findViewById(R.id.signout)
        uploadData = findViewById(R.id.btnUpload)
        textToBeUpload = findViewById(R.id.editTextData)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()


        //log user out
        signoutButton.setOnClickListener{
            mAuth.signOut()
            startActivity(Intent(this@HomePage, MainActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }

        //upload data to cloud firestore
        uploadData.setOnClickListener{

            var city = hashMapOf(
                "description" to "${textToBeUpload.text}",
                "state" to "dummies data",
                "country" to "USA"
            )

           database.collection("Users").document(database.collection("Users").document().id).set(city).addOnSuccessListener {

           }.addOnFailureListener{

               //currentUser?.displayName.toString()
           }
        }

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val currentUser = mAuth.currentUser
        if(currentUser != null){
            display.text = "current user is ${currentUser.email}"
        }else{
            display.text = "it is empty"
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Login : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var email : EditText
    private lateinit var password : EditText
    private lateinit var btnLoginButton : Button
   // private lateinit var mAuth : FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var logUserIn : FirebaseAuthentication

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        setTitle("Firebase user Login")

        email = findViewById(R.id.myEmail)
        password = findViewById(R.id.myPassword)
        btnLoginButton = findViewById(R.id.button2)
       // mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        logUserIn = FirebaseAuthentication()

        btnLoginButton.setOnClickListener{

            logUserIn.logTheUserIn(email.text.toString().trim(), password.text.toString().trim())

            startActivity(Intent(this@Login,HomePage::class.java))
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time your `val currentUser = mAuth.currentUser` runs, the user may not have been set yet. If you want to make sure that you get notified of the user, use an auth state change listener:

```
mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        currentUserID = currentUser.getUid();
        if (user != null ) {
            display.text = "current user is ${currentUser.email}"
        }
        else {
            display.text = "it is empty"
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: well i gotta convert this to kotlin code but yes it does work after a few attempt. kinda new to this